# Execute Remote Script on Server by Means of SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a remote script on a remote server:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Parameters=$@
echo "Ciao" $1
```

I run the script by invokin an ssh connection:

```
❯ pippo=pluto 
❯ ssh   -i rsa_r developer@test.io "deploy.sh $pippo"
Parameters=
Ciao
(base)"
```

Why it is not getting the parameter $pippo?

Adding the -v option to get some insights:

```
...
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/developer/.ssh/authorized_keys:6: key options: agent-forwarding command port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/developer/.ssh/authorized_keys:6: key options: agent-forwarding command port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: deploy.sh $pippo
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Parameters=
Ciao
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3264, received 3128 bytes, in 1.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2228.4, received 2135.6
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Also, changing the parameter to `pippo` instead of `$pippo` does not matter.
To the skeptical:

[image]

Comment: Are you SURE that's the exact code you're running and not `ssh -i rsa_r developer@test.io 'deploy.sh $pippo'` or `ssh -i rsa_r developer@test.io 'deploy.sh "$pippo"'` or anything else?

Comment: yes, I just copy&pasted the shell commands I ran...

Comment: Please type `set -x` to turn on tracing then run those commands and copy/paste the result into your question. You may also want to add `-v`, `-vv`, or `-vvv` to your `ssh` command to see what it's doing in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The local shell has been prevented from expanding the variable `$pippo` to the value `pluto`, and the `ssh` command is seeing the literal string `deploy.sh $pippo`:

> ```
> debug1: Sending command: deploy.sh $pippo
> ```

The remote shell evaluates `$pippo` and finds it's empty, resulting in it executing `deploy.sh` with no arguments.

I would suggest that the command you're executing is not the one you've shown us. Please double check the quotation marks: it's very likely you're actually using single quotes rather than double quotes.

Incidentally your script should double quote the variables it's using:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Parameters=$*"
echo "Ciao $1"
```

Comment: see the picture I added: the command are there. no trick.